# OrderedDict Changing Order after Double Iterator Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, ordereddictionary

I set up an `OrderedDict` and perform dictionary comprehensions with different grammars, which I have simplified to a function `dictcomp(fn, dictionary, key_or_value):`:

```
    x = OrderedDict(self._Median_Colors)
    x = self.dictcomp(hex2color, x, 'v')
    x = self.dictcomp(rgb_to_hsv, x, 'v_tuple')
```

At this point I am able to sort the dictionary:

```
    x = self.dictcomp(self.sort_by_hue, x, 'v')
```

Everything seems to check out so far:

```
    print x
```

Now I need to rename keys, so I will create a new ordered dictionary:

```
    color_indexes = list(xrange(0, len(x.keys())))
    print color_indexes

    newkeys = [self.rename(color_index) for color_index in color_indexes]

    print x.values()
    vi = iter(x.values())
    x = OrderedDict.fromkeys(newkeys);
```

I had no idea how to fill in the old values immediately, so I did this:

```
    ki = iter(x.keys())
    for k, v in zip(ki, vi):
        #print "k:", k
        print  v
        x[k] = tuple(v)
```

Checks out fine:

```
    print x.items()
```

Here comes trouble:

```
    x = self.dictcomp(hsv_to_rgb, x, 'v_tuple')
    print x.items()
```

where dictcomp does this:

```
    dictionary = {k: fn(*v) for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

where `fn=hsv_to_rgb`, `dictionary=x`

Now, I have:

```
[('Blue', (0.9764705882352941, 0.5529411764705883, 0.0)), ....
```

instead of the expected:

```
[('Red', (0.4745098039215686, 0.7372549019607844, 0.23137254901960794)), ....
```

The keys are the same, but the values have changed. I am guessing that the insertion order was somehow affected. How did this happen and how can I keep the order of keys in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of

```
for i, j in zip([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]):
    print i
    print j
```

Results in the column:

`4 1 5 2 6 3`

It turns out that zip acts as a zipper if using two iterators.

The fix is to get the keyword-value as an iterable tuple:

```
for i in zip([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]):
    print i
```

Returns

```
(4, 1)
(5, 2)
(6, 3)
```